How to convert the JSONLD schema to Class objects in JavaScript application?
I would like to convert a JSONLD document into a Class and properties in JavaScript. Something similar to Java where we have a class with variables and I want to achieve the similar thing for my JavaScript application.
I have a complex JSONLD schema which I cannot build the complete Class relations from it so planning to achieve it using the npm package so I found json-schema-to-ts and json-schema-to-typescript. Is there any better library to achieve the requirement?
I am developing the application in Nuxt 3/Vue 3 so when I use it then I am unable to open my file at all and get the error:
pages/Test.vue:
<template></template>
    
<script setup>  
  const vocabURL = "";
  
  import { ref } from "vue";
  import {
    fetchJsonLdData,
    parseJsonLdData,
  } from "~/composables/myComposable.js";
  
  onMounted(async () => {
    await fetchJsonLdData(vocabURL);
    await parseJsonLdData2();
  });
  </script>

~/composables/myComposable.js:
import jsonld from "jsonld";
import { FromSchema } from "json-schema-to-ts";
const jsonLdData = useState("jsonLdData", () => null);

//Fetch data from the URL
export async function fetchJsonLdData(vocabURL) {
  const response = await fetch(vocabURL);
  jsonLdData.value = await response.json();
}

export async function parseJsonLdData2() {
  //Get the compacted JSON Schema contents
  const { "@context": context } = jsonLdData.value;
  const compacted = await jsonld.compact(jsonLdData.value, context);
}

I have not even used the FromSchema from json-schema-to-ts but I get the error:
SyntaxError: The requested module '/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/deps/json-schema-to-ts.js?v=f089a1a6' does not provide an export named 'FromSchema'

As per documentation they are using the FromSchema: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-ts
Similarly I used the json-schema-to-typescript
When I just add the following line then I get the error.
import { compileFromFile } from "json-schema-to-typescript";
Then I get the error:
vue-router.js?v=75beb15c:2504 ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at node_modules/@bcherny/json-schema-ref-parser/cjs/util/projectDir.cjs (json-schema-to-typescript.js?v=75beb15c:23733:39)

I would like to read the JSON-LD schema file and convert it into a JavaScript object with respective parent-child relationship. I want a generic way of reading any type of the JSON-LD schema without any hardcoding.
I have following JSON-LD example file:
{
  "@id": "test:GrowingMethodCode-CONVENTIONAL",
  "@type": "test:GrowingMethodCode",
  "rdfs:comment": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Foods grown non-organically, either indoors or outdoors without any special processes."
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Conventional"
  },
  "skos:prefLabel": "CONVENTIONAL"
},
{
  "@id": "test:GrowingMethodCode-FARM_RAISED",
  "@type": "test:GrowingMethodCode",
  "rdfs:comment": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Animal is raised on a farm."
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Farm Raised"
  },
  "skos:prefLabel": "FARM_RAISED"
},
  {
  "@id": "test:nutritionalClaim",
  "@type": [
    "owl:ObjectProperty",
    "rdf:Property"
  ],
  "rdfs:comment": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Code indicating a nutritional claim applicable to the product, for example FAT_FREE."
  },
  "rdfs:domain": {
    "@id": "test:FoodBeverageTobaccoProduct"
  },
  "rdfs:isDefinedBy": {
    "@id": "test:"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Nutritional Claim Code"
  },
  "rdfs:range": {
    "@id": "test:NutritionalClaimTypeCode"
  },
  "sw:term_status": "stable"
  }

Within the schema itself I have the respective class as well:
{
  "@id": "test:FoodBeverageTobaccoProduct",
  "@type": [
    "rdfs:Class",
    "owl:Class"
  ],
  "rdfs:comment": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "A food, beverage or tobacco product."
  },
  "rdfs:isDefinedBy": {
    "@id": "test:"
  },
  "rdfs:label": {
    "@language": "en",
    "@value": "Food Beverage Tobacco Product"
  },
  "rdfs:subClassOf": {
    "@id": "test:Product"
  },
  "sw:term_status": "stable"
},
{
    "@id": "test:DietTypeCode",
    "rdfs:label": {
        "@language": "en",
        "@value": "Diet Type Code"
    },
    "rdfs:subClassOf": {
        "@id": "test:TypeCode"
    }
}

Like this I have a complex JSON-LD schema with various properties, class, subclass, Typecode etc. I want to create a JavaScript object where I have all the information in tree format with main class followed by its properties, if the property is again a class then its properties to include the complex relations as well.
I would like to know if I can use any libraries to achieve this rather than looping over the JSON-LD schema and building the relation. I have already tried using the jsonld npm package but it works to certain extent but for most of the things I need to do it manually by various checks etc. Hence I am looking for some easy approach which does everything automatically and provides me with the relation.

" I get the error" - it means TS type that doesn't exist at runtime leaks to runtime. FromSchema is TS type, it doesn't make sense to use it in .js file. It's unclear what's your intention with "Class and properties in JavaScript. Something similar to Java". What is it supposed to look like? I see people with java background constantly having issues with js/ts as this aspect works differently there. Currently you're trying to use TS-specific libs in JS app, which defies their purpose for the most part

I am looking for a direct approach to convert a complex JSON-LD schema into a JavaScript Object which contains all the relations such as parent-child. I am adding the example in the above question

@EstusFlask I would like to traverse the JSON-LD schema and build a kind of relationship tree. Like this I have JSON-LD schema https://www.gs1.org/docs/gs1-smartsearch/gs1Voc_v1_9.jsonld which has quite complex structure and elements for which I am looking for a library which can recursively read and get a parent-child or tree kind of relationship with all the values.

@EstusFlask Please let me know if you know of any npm package or some library which can help me convert the JSON-LD into a tree with ease in JavaScript.

Not aware of such. I ended up handling jsonld manually for my needs. But "jsonld" package can be a good starter. Your case narrows down the choice of libs because it seemingly requires to parse an object dynamically on client side, which is rare. Not the case for json-schema-to-typescript, for instance, it's Node

@EstusFlask Thanks a lot for the response. Yes, I used the jsonld package but I need to handle it manually there and there are a lot of edge cases which I need to handle so wanted to know if there is any better way to do it than doing it manually. I was hoping to find some library which can parse JSON-LD schema and provide me with a complete relation tree.
